# Wordpress loading multiple jQuery Versions

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i developed a plugin that uses the jquery booklet plugin (http://builtbywill.com/booklet/#/) this plugin binds a function to $ so I cann call $(".myBook").booklet();

I could easy managing the loading order with wp_enqueue_script so first I load jquery then I load booklet so everything is fine.

BUT in my theme i also using jquery via webpack so the loading order is now follogin:

1. jquery
2. booklet
3. app.js (bundled file with webpack, including jquery)

so from now $.booklet isn't available because jquery gets again loaded.

Now my question is how can i solve this problem with only updating the plugin no the themes? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Do you really need to use multiple versions of jQuery? Doing that normally creates more problems than it solves

Comment: no, no, no exactly BECAUSE i have multiple versions (wordpress loads jquery and my theme loads jquery) it causes problems